# Is it possible to gain admission to an engineering master's program without an undergraduate engineering degree?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, career-path, engineering, economics

I tried to search for this and could not find it. This is my first stack exchange post so go easy please.

Here is my situation.

I have an undergraduate degree in economics from a top tier economics program, and a very top tier university in general, with a GPA above 3.5. After working in economics research at a highly respected institution for 2 years after graduating, I've realized I want to pursue a different career. The work I do is highly quantitative and involves some computer programming using C++. I'm also pretty good with mathematical and data analysis/statistical software, and have worked multiple RA jobs as an undergraduate.

Ideally I would do something related to software engineering or electrical engineering since I'm interested in computers. My question is, to what extent is this possible? Is it possible at all? Will universities see that I don't have an undergraduate engineering degree and reject me? Do I have any sort of shot here given my background?

Comment: The "roommate of mine" of mine who I mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2836764/13130) got an undergraduate degree in math, skipped a year from school (worked as an assistant car mechanic), then took some undergraduate engineering courses at another university part-time, then applied to and got accepted to MIT's graduate mechanical engineering program, where he got his Ph.D. in mechanical engineering a few years later. So yes, it is possible.